# Why opendir gets SIGABRT error

Tags: c, unix, posix

I have a problem when i am using opendir to open a directory in my program.

I am using this lines to do that:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int i;
    int Port,TPS,QS,Height,Number_kids;
    char server_ip[16];
    DIR * directory;
    struct ps *parms = (struct ps*)malloc(sizeof(struct ps));

    if(argc!=8)
    {
        printf("Wrong number of arguents given!!!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Port=atoi(argv[2]);
    TPS=atoi(argv[3]);
    QS=atoi(argv[4]);
    Height=atoi(argv[5]);
    Number_kids=atoi(argv[6]);

    strcpy(server_ip,argv[1]);
    strcpy(parms->directory,argv[7]);


    if(Height<2 || Number_kids<2)
    {
        printf("Wrong parameters given!!!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for(i=2;i<7;i++)
    {
        int temp=atoi(argv[i]);
        if(temp<=0)
        {
            printf("Wrong parameters given!!!\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    directory = opendir(parms->directory);
    if(directory == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error when trying to open specified directory:");
        return;
    }
}
```

where `parms->directory` is

```
struct ps
{
    char directory[50];
};
```

The directory function contains a directory path: /home/user/Desktop/folder 
(The path is correct)

When i run my program without the debugger i am getting this error:

```
    malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) *
 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) 
(old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof
(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)
old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

I can figure from that is something wrong inside the function opendir when it uses malloc (?)

Whern i run the debugger I'm getting a SIGABRT signal and the same error. (I am using Netbeans)

I can't figure what I am doing wrong with that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If `malloc()` fails in this way it is almost certainly a bug in your program, and the bug is almost certainly somewhere else.  The bug might be in a completely unrelated piece of code.

These errors are usually caused by memory corruption.  Run your program using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or compile with [Mudflap](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Mudflap_Pointer_Debugging) enabled.  These have to be installed, but they are an essential part of your toolbox if you are writing code in C.  They are much more likely point out the parts of your program which are actually causing memory corruption.

Comment: I used valgrind and it shows nothing wrong with the rest of my code. I appears to have a corruption of heap in opendir function. I am not doing something really complicated in that program. It just a main function that tries only to do that open.

Comment: If it's really just a `main()` function, post the whole program.  You can post to Gist (https://gist.github.com) or paste the whole program in your question, depending on how long it is.

Comment: @Blenikos: I noticed that your code uses `strcpy()` with untrusted input, which is never safe.  Are you sure that `strlen(argv[1]) <= 15`?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure about that. it's just an ip4 address. so it's 3*4=12 +1 for '\0' character